# Integrating with Dynamics CRM - REST vs. XML vs. SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I put together some code for accessing CRM using the DLL's provided in the SDK download and tried out both the early binding approach and late binding approach.

What I'd like to do is in addition to having some custom entities that my users will access in Dynamics (through the Dynamics UI in the cloud), I also want to build some Android apps that talk to Dynamics.

My understanding is that I can talk to Dynamics from Android via REST (assuming I properly handle the authentication and getting tokens using ADAL libraries since my Dynamics instances run on the Microsoft cloud) or I can use the SDK with .NET as a middle-tier.

What's the recommended approach? Is there a best practice? When would I use the DLL's provided in the SDK and maybe wrap them in my own Web API vs. connecting to Dynamics directly via REST?

Please help this noob.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hard to say, depends on your talents and needs.  Here is a great website link to get started though:
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2015/01/12/build-your-own-crm-mobile-app-s.aspx

Just a note on the Rest calls, you can only perform CRUD operations by default, and will need to jump through some hoops to perform the other calls.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2015/01/12/build-your-own-crm-mobile-app-s.aspx
@Daryl, your link has a %20 prefix for some reason.